# Changing innerHTML on link by id

Tags: javascript, html, url, innerhtml

I am trying to change the innerHTML of the anchor element with the help of the id of the same element displayed below in the label marked "html".

```
JS:
onload=function(){
var localUrl = document.URL
localUrl = localUrl.split('http://')[1].split('/');
document.getElementById('menuDomain').innerHTML = localUrl[0];
}

html: <a id="menuDomain" href=".."></a>
```

But the innerHTML of the anchor element remains unchanged. :(

Comment: maybe `window.onload`? This works: http://jsfiddle.net/Daess/qjHWX/

Comment: You have to call your `onload` function somehow. I've tested it http://jsfiddle.net/9qdQY/ and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: the onload function is working well, my other functions seems to be working
but the menuDomain staying unchanged.
Could it means problem if my a element is inside an ul ? i thought it shouldnt.

Comment: I tested it in Safari and its working, so firefox has a problem with my code

Comment: Can you post the complete url of this page ?

Comment: for example: http://localhost/test/admin/admin.php?page=menuEdit

Safari prints: localhost
FF: nothing
IE: nothing

Comment: Hm, now it is working, IE was in "compatibility view" and maybe I checked the wrong document (not the updated) in FF. :S
So it is working with:
onload=function()
Maybe my problem was the semicolon .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well work better when you add a semicolon after the `document.URL`...

```
var localUrl = document.URL;
```